# Beginner in R : writing my first function work only for one variable

Tags: r, function, if-statement, numeric

I am a beginner in R. I am actually trying to code my first function.

I am looking for csv files in a directory on my computer, then I put them into a data frame and then I am asking for the mean of some variable.

I have 2 variable : sulfate and nitrate.

My function works fine for nitrate but not for sulfate. I really don't know what is wrong. R studio gave me a clue : In mean.default(directory$suftate, na.rm = TRUE) :

> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

But I don't know what to do with this information.

My function is :

```
 pollutantmean <- function (directory, polluant = "nitrate", id = 1:332)
 directory <- data.frame()
 for (i in id)
{directory <- rbind(directory, read.csv(full_files[i]))} 
if (polluant == "nitrate"){
mean(directory$nitrate,na.rm = TRUE)} 
else if (polluant == "sulfate"){
mean(directory$suftate,na.rm = TRUE)}
else {print("KO")}
}
```

Can you help me ?

Caroline

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pollutantmean) for an answer? This Coursera topic has 136 reaults on SO already

Comment: Hello Caroline. This is a homework assignment, and per the Coursera Honor Code you're not allowed to post complete answers to homework assignments on the internet.

Comment: Hi @LenGreski, it's not totally the answer... it's not working! And the teacher encourage you to ask for help ;)

Comment: The [Coursera Honor Code](https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/209818863) specifically states, "You may not share your solutions to homework, quizzes, or exams with anyone else unless explicitly permitted by the instructor."  In the JHU curriculum, some assignments (e.g. those students must post to GitHub or RPubs) have explicit permission to be shared.  When a student has a problem s/he is allowed to post some code, but not an entire answer, regardless of whether the code is working. I recognize the Coursera policy is in conflict with the SO definition of a good question.

Answer (score 0):

1. An opening curly brace is missing in the very first line
2. This function will only work if there exists a global variable called `full_files`; consider passing it to
   the function explicitly
3. Likely a typo in the `else if` clause: `directory$sulfate`, not `directory$suftate`
4. This function does not return anything; executing it won't actually do anything. Well, technically, 
   running `mean()` prints some output, but it may not always be the case, especially when run from the 
   command line, or when called from another function or script. Consider wrapping `mean()` in `print()` (or, even better, `return`ing it, which will allow you to assign the mean to other variables)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I really wanted to do it myself :) without copy another function. However I am so sorry because, I haven't see the wrong speeling. It's now ok. Thanks !